# PHP - DateTime::createFromFormat seems not to find the pattern

Tags: php, datetime, format

I have the following date: `(Tue 7:00AM EST)`.

Now in order to change its format to `2014-01-21 7:00`, I made use of `DateTime:createFromFormat()` and `DateTime::format()`. However, it does not seem to find the pattern in the string mentioned above.

Here's the code:

```
<?php

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('(D g:iA T)', '(Tue 7:00AM EST)');
if($date !== false) {
    var_dump($date->format('Y-m-d H:i'));
} else {
    echo 'Invalid date!';
}

?>

Prints: Invalid Date!
```

Comment: Have you tried `trim`ming out the brackets?

Comment: **https://eval.in/92935**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trim out the brackets:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('D g:iA T', trim('(Tue 7:00AM EST)', '()'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`print_r(DateTime::getLastErrors(),1);` gave me:

> Array (
>       [warning_count] => 0
>       [warnings] => Array
>           (
>           )
>
> ```
> [error_count] => 1
> [errors] => Array
>     (
>         [16] => Data missing
>     )
> ```
>
> )

which means at index 16 of the string '(Tue 7:00AM EST)' there is data missing (at the last bracket).

`echo print_r(DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers());` lists the following timezones

> ```
> Array (
> [0] => Africa/Abidjan
> [1] => Africa/Accra
> [2] => Africa/Addis_Ababa
> [3] => Africa/Algiers
> [4] => Africa/Asmara
> [5] => Africa/Bamako
> [6] => Africa/Bangui
> [7] => Africa/Banjul
> [8] => Africa/Bissau
> [9] => Africa/Blantyre
> [10] => Africa/Brazzaville
> [11] => Africa/Bujumbura
> [12] => Africa/Cairo
> [13] => Africa/Casablanca
> [14] => Africa/Ceuta
> [15] => Africa/Conakry
> [16] => Africa/Dakar
> [17] => Africa/Dar_es_Salaam
> [18] => Africa/Djibouti
> [19] => Africa/Douala
> [20] => Africa/El_Aaiun
> [21] => Africa/Freetown
> [22] => Africa/Gaborone
> [23] => Africa/Harare
> [24] => Africa/Johannesburg
> [25] => Africa/Juba
> [26] => Africa/Kampala
> [27] => Africa/Khartoum
> [28] => Africa/Kigali
> [29] => Africa/Kinshasa
> [30] => Africa/Lagos
> [31] => Africa/Libreville
> [32] => Africa/Lome
> [33] => Africa/Luanda
> [34] => Africa/Lubumbashi
> [35] => Africa/Lusaka
> [36] => Africa/Malabo
> [37] => Africa/Maputo
> [38] => Africa/Maseru
> [39] => Africa/Mbabane
> [40] => Africa/Mogadishu
> [41] => Africa/Monrovia
> [42] => Africa/Nairobi
> [43] => Africa/Ndjamena
> [44] => Africa/Niamey
> [45] => Africa/Nouakchott
> [46] => Africa/Ouagadougou
> [47] => Africa/Porto-Novo
> [48] => Africa/Sao_Tome
> [49] => Africa/Tripoli
> [50] => Africa/Tunis
> [51] => Africa/Windhoek
> [52] => America/Adak
> [53] => America/Anchorage
> [54] => America/Anguilla
> [55] => America/Antigua
> [56] => America/Araguaina
> [57] => America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires
> [58] => America/Argentina/Catamarca
> [59] => America/Argentina/Cordoba
> [60] => America/Argentina/Jujuy
> [61] => America/Argentina/La_Rioja
> [62] => America/Argentina/Mendoza
> [63] => America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos
> [64] => America/Argentina/Salta
> [65] => America/Argentina/San_Juan
> [66] => America/Argentina/San_Luis
> [67] => America/Argentina/Tucuman
> [68] => America/Argentina/Ushuaia
> [69] => America/Aruba
> [70] => America/Asuncion
> [71] => America/Atikokan
> [72] => America/Bahia
> [73] => America/Bahia_Banderas
> [74] => America/Barbados
> [75] => America/Belem
> [76] => America/Belize
> [77] => America/Blanc-Sablon
> [78] => America/Boa_Vista
> [79] => America/Bogota
> [80] => America/Boise
> [81] => America/Cambridge_Bay
> [82] => America/Campo_Grande
> [83] => America/Cancun
> [84] => America/Caracas
> [85] => America/Cayenne
> [86] => America/Cayman
> [87] => America/Chicago
> [88] => America/Chihuahua
> [89] => America/Costa_Rica
> [90] => America/Creston
> [91] => America/Cuiaba
> [92] => America/Curacao
> [93] => America/Danmarkshavn
> [94] => America/Dawson
> [95] => America/Dawson_Creek
> [96] => America/Denver
> [97] => America/Detroit
> [98] => America/Dominica
> [99] => America/Edmonton
> [100] => America/Eirunepe
> [101] => America/El_Salvador
> [102] => America/Fortaleza
> [103] => America/Glace_Bay
> [104] => America/Godthab
> [105] => America/Goose_Bay
> [106] => America/Grand_Turk
> [107] => America/Grenada
> [108] => America/Guadeloupe
> [109] => America/Guatemala
> [110] => America/Guayaquil
> [111] => America/Guyana
> [112] => America/Halifax
> [113] => America/Havana
> [114] => America/Hermosillo
> [115] => America/Indiana/Indianapolis
> [116] => America/Indiana/Knox
> [117] => America/Indiana/Marengo
> [118] => America/Indiana/Petersburg
> [119] => America/Indiana/Tell_City
> [120] => America/Indiana/Vevay
> [121] => America/Indiana/Vincennes
> [122] => America/Indiana/Winamac
> [123] => America/Inuvik
> [124] => America/Iqaluit
> [125] => America/Jamaica
> [126] => America/Juneau
> [127] => America/Kentucky/Louisville
> [128] => America/Kentucky/Monticello
> [129] => America/Kralendijk
> [130] => America/La_Paz
> [131] => America/Lima
> [132] => America/Los_Angeles
> [133] => America/Lower_Princes
> [134] => America/Maceio
> [135] => America/Managua
> [136] => America/Manaus
> [137] => America/Marigot
> [138] => America/Martinique
> [139] => America/Matamoros
> [140] => America/Mazatlan
> [141] => America/Menominee
> [142] => America/Merida
> [143] => America/Metlakatla
> [144] => America/Mexico_City
> [145] => America/Miquelon
> [146] => America/Moncton
> [147] => America/Monterrey
> [148] => America/Montevideo
> [149] => America/Montserrat
> [150] => America/Nassau
> [151] => America/New_York
> [152] => America/Nipigon
> [153] => America/Nome
> [154] => America/Noronha
> [155] => America/North_Dakota/Beulah
> [156] => America/North_Dakota/Center
> [157] => America/North_Dakota/New_Salem
> [158] => America/Ojinaga
> [159] => America/Panama
> [160] => America/Pangnirtung
> [161] => America/Paramaribo
> [162] => America/Phoenix
> [163] => America/Port-au-Prince
> [164] => America/Port_of_Spain
> [165] => America/Porto_Velho
> [166] => America/Puerto_Rico
> [167] => America/Rainy_River
> [168] => America/Rankin_Inlet
> [169] => America/Recife
> [170] => America/Regina
> [171] => America/Resolute
> [172] => America/Rio_Branco
> [173] => America/Santa_Isabel
> [174] => America/Santarem
> [175] => America/Santiago
> [176] => America/Santo_Domingo
> [177] => America/Sao_Paulo
> [178] => America/Scoresbysund
> [179] => America/Sitka
> [180] => America/St_Barthelemy
> [181] => America/St_Johns
> [182] => America/St_Kitts
> [183] => America/St_Lucia
> [184] => America/St_Thomas
> [185] => America/St_Vincent
> [186] => America/Swift_Current
> [187] => America/Tegucigalpa
> [188] => America/Thule
> [189] => America/Thunder_Bay
> [190] => America/Tijuana
> [191] => America/Toronto
> [192] => America/Tortola
> [193] => America/Vancouver
> [194] => America/Whitehorse
> [195] => America/Winnipeg
> [196] => America/Yakutat
> [197] => America/Yellowknife
> [198] => Antarctica/Casey
> [199] => Antarctica/Davis
> [200] => Antarctica/DumontDUrville
> [201] => Antarctica/Macquarie
> [202] => Antarctica/Mawson
> [203] => Antarctica/McMurdo
> [204] => Antarctica/Palmer
> [205] => Antarctica/Rothera
> [206] => Antarctica/Syowa
> [207] => Antarctica/Vostok
> [208] => Arctic/Longyearbyen
> [209] => Asia/Aden
> [210] => Asia/Almaty
> [211] => Asia/Amman
> [212] => Asia/Anadyr
> [213] => Asia/Aqtau
> [214] => Asia/Aqtobe
> [215] => Asia/Ashgabat
> [216] => Asia/Baghdad
> [217] => Asia/Bahrain
> [218] => Asia/Baku
> [219] => Asia/Bangkok
> [220] => Asia/Beirut
> [221] => Asia/Bishkek
> [222] => Asia/Brunei
> [223] => Asia/Choibalsan
> [224] => Asia/Chongqing
> [225] => Asia/Colombo
> [226] => Asia/Damascus
> [227] => Asia/Dhaka
> [228] => Asia/Dili
> [229] => Asia/Dubai
> [230] => Asia/Dushanbe
> [231] => Asia/Gaza
> [232] => Asia/Harbin
> [233] => Asia/Hebron
> [234] => Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh
> [235] => Asia/Hong_Kong
> [236] => Asia/Hovd
> [237] => Asia/Irkutsk
> [238] => Asia/Jakarta
> [239] => Asia/Jayapura
> [240] => Asia/Jerusalem
> [241] => Asia/Kabul
> [242] => Asia/Kamchatka
> [243] => Asia/Karachi
> [244] => Asia/Kashgar
> [245] => Asia/Kathmandu
> [246] => Asia/Khandyga
> [247] => Asia/Kolkata
> [248] => Asia/Krasnoyarsk
> [249] => Asia/Kuala_Lumpur
> [250] => Asia/Kuching
> [251] => Asia/Kuwait
> [252] => Asia/Macau
> [253] => Asia/Magadan
> [254] => Asia/Makassar
> [255] => Asia/Manila
> [256] => Asia/Muscat
> [257] => Asia/Nicosia
> [258] => Asia/Novokuznetsk
> [259] => Asia/Novosibirsk
> [260] => Asia/Omsk
> [261] => Asia/Oral
> [262] => Asia/Phnom_Penh
> [263] => Asia/Pontianak
> [264] => Asia/Pyongyang
> [265] => Asia/Qatar
> [266] => Asia/Qyzylorda
> [267] => Asia/Rangoon
> [268] => Asia/Riyadh
> [269] => Asia/Sakhalin
> [270] => Asia/Samarkand
> [271] => Asia/Seoul
> [272] => Asia/Shanghai
> [273] => Asia/Singapore
> [274] => Asia/Taipei
> [275] => Asia/Tashkent
> [276] => Asia/Tbilisi
> [277] => Asia/Tehran
> [278] => Asia/Thimphu
> [279] => Asia/Tokyo
> [280] => Asia/Ulaanbaatar
> [281] => Asia/Urumqi
> [282] => Asia/Ust-Nera
> [283] => Asia/Vientiane
> [284] => Asia/Vladivostok
> [285] => Asia/Yakutsk
> [286] => Asia/Yekaterinburg
> [287] => Asia/Yerevan
> [288] => Atlantic/Azores
> [289] => Atlantic/Bermuda
> [290] => Atlantic/Canary
> [291] => Atlantic/Cape_Verde
> [292] => Atlantic/Faroe
> [293] => Atlantic/Madeira
> [294] => Atlantic/Reykjavik
> [295] => Atlantic/South_Georgia
> [296] => Atlantic/St_Helena
> [297] => Atlantic/Stanley
> [298] => Australia/Adelaide
> [299] => Australia/Brisbane
> [300] => Australia/Broken_Hill
> [301] => Australia/Currie
> [302] => Australia/Darwin
> [303] => Australia/Eucla
> [304] => Australia/Hobart
> [305] => Australia/Lindeman
> [306] => Australia/Lord_Howe
> [307] => Australia/Melbourne
> [308] => Australia/Perth
> [309] => Australia/Sydney
> [310] => Europe/Amsterdam
> [311] => Europe/Andorra
> [312] => Europe/Athens
> [313] => Europe/Belgrade
> [314] => Europe/Berlin
> [315] => Europe/Bratislava
> [316] => Europe/Brussels
> [317] => Europe/Bucharest
> [318] => Europe/Budapest
> [319] => Europe/Busingen
> [320] => Europe/Chisinau
> [321] => Europe/Copenhagen
> [322] => Europe/Dublin
> [323] => Europe/Gibraltar
> [324] => Europe/Guernsey
> [325] => Europe/Helsinki
> [326] => Europe/Isle_of_Man
> [327] => Europe/Istanbul
> [328] => Europe/Jersey
> [329] => Europe/Kaliningrad
> [330] => Europe/Kiev
> [331] => Europe/Lisbon
> [332] => Europe/Ljubljana
> [333] => Europe/London
> [334] => Europe/Luxembourg
> [335] => Europe/Madrid
> [336] => Europe/Malta
> [337] => Europe/Mariehamn
> [338] => Europe/Minsk
> [339] => Europe/Monaco
> [340] => Europe/Moscow
> [341] => Europe/Oslo
> [342] => Europe/Paris
> [343] => Europe/Podgorica
> [344] => Europe/Prague
> [345] => Europe/Riga
> [346] => Europe/Rome
> [347] => Europe/Samara
> [348] => Europe/San_Marino
> [349] => Europe/Sarajevo
> [350] => Europe/Simferopol
> [351] => Europe/Skopje
> [352] => Europe/Sofia
> [353] => Europe/Stockholm
> [354] => Europe/Tallinn
> [355] => Europe/Tirane
> [356] => Europe/Uzhgorod
> [357] => Europe/Vaduz
> [358] => Europe/Vatican
> [359] => Europe/Vienna
> [360] => Europe/Vilnius
> [361] => Europe/Volgograd
> [362] => Europe/Warsaw
> [363] => Europe/Zagreb
> [364] => Europe/Zaporozhye
> [365] => Europe/Zurich
> [366] => Indian/Antananarivo
> [367] => Indian/Chagos
> [368] => Indian/Christmas
> [369] => Indian/Cocos
> [370] => Indian/Comoro
> [371] => Indian/Kerguelen
> [372] => Indian/Mahe
> [373] => Indian/Maldives
> [374] => Indian/Mauritius
> [375] => Indian/Mayotte
> [376] => Indian/Reunion
> [377] => Pacific/Apia
> [378] => Pacific/Auckland
> [379] => Pacific/Chatham
> [380] => Pacific/Chuuk
> [381] => Pacific/Easter
> [382] => Pacific/Efate
> [383] => Pacific/Enderbury
> [384] => Pacific/Fakaofo
> [385] => Pacific/Fiji
> [386] => Pacific/Funafuti
> [387] => Pacific/Galapagos
> [388] => Pacific/Gambier
> [389] => Pacific/Guadalcanal
> [390] => Pacific/Guam
> [391] => Pacific/Honolulu
> [392] => Pacific/Johnston
> [393] => Pacific/Kiritimati
> [394] => Pacific/Kosrae
> [395] => Pacific/Kwajalein
> [396] => Pacific/Majuro
> [397] => Pacific/Marquesas
> [398] => Pacific/Midway
> [399] => Pacific/Nauru
> [400] => Pacific/Niue
> [401] => Pacific/Norfolk
> [402] => Pacific/Noumea
> [403] => Pacific/Pago_Pago
> [404] => Pacific/Palau
> [405] => Pacific/Pitcairn
> [406] => Pacific/Pohnpei
> [407] => Pacific/Port_Moresby
> [408] => Pacific/Rarotonga
> [409] => Pacific/Saipan
> [410] => Pacific/Tahiti
> [411] => Pacific/Tarawa
> [412] => Pacific/Tongatapu
> [413] => Pacific/Wake
> [414] => Pacific/Wallis
> [415] => UTC
> )
> ```

So there is not EST listed. However `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('T', 'EST');` works without problems, in contrast to `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('(T)', '(EST)');`.

I could not manage to get exactly that example working, but maybe my mentioned thoughts can help you.

BTW: The following worked for me:

- Removing the brackets (maybe the easiest solution)
- `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('(D g:iA)', '(Tue 7:00AM)');` (without timezone)

Comment: EST is supported, [demo](https://eval.in/92976). If timezone wouldn't be supported, you would get error: `The timezone could not be found in the database`, like this [demo](https://eval.in/92978).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to trim out the brackets, your date format can be parsed by `\DateTime::createFromFormat()` without any problems:-

```
$dateStr = "(Tue 7:00AM EST)";
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat("(D g:iA T", $dateStr);
var_dump($date);
```

You will notice that the trick is to leave out the trailing `)`.

Output:-

```
object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '2014-01-21 07:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 2
  public 'timezone' => string 'EST' (length=3)
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/5LhHP) and the manual for [formats accepted by `DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).